# Virality algorithm for different type of objects

Tags: algorithm, ranking

For a project I need to rank certain objects based on events on/with that specific object. But the objects to be ranked aren't alike.

Some background: the application is a social-network-like document-management system. There are a lot of users, who can upload/post 'documents' of various types (video's, external articles - eg. found on a relevant blog -, articles written within the system itself etc.). But also user-to-user messages should appear in the feed, as well as system messages, etc.

To break it down a little, let's assume these three objects should appear in the news-feed, ranked/sorted on virality, which is based on events.

- Documents
- System messages
- User-to-user, or user-to-group) messages

A few parameters that are important for the ranking, per object:

- Documents

  - Number of views
  - Number of comments
  - Number of shares
  - Affinity with the document (user has commented on it, shared it, etc.)
  - Correspondence of tags the user is enlisted to
- System messages

  - Importancy level (eg. 'Notice', 'Announcement')
- User/group messages

  - Level of engagement in the conversation

And to make it harder, the date the object was created is important, as well as the date and correlation of the occuring events. And to add up one more to the complexity: pretty much everything is relative; eg. the number of views for a document needed to define it as 'viral' and as such make it appear in the news-feed depends on the average number of views. Same goes for comments, but for comments the posted date and time between posting of new comments is important as well.... (oh and in case it wasn't clear, ranking is always relative to a user, not system-wide).

My first thought was to define a max score (`Sm`) for each object, define when an object reaches the `Sm` and calculate the actual score (`Sa`). Ie. the system messages have a `Sm` of 100, user/group messages 80 and documents have a `Sm` of 60. This means that if one of each object is created at exactly the same time, and no other parameters (comments etc.) are available yet, the system message will be listed first, the user message will come next, and last, but not least, the document.

So for each type of object, I'm looking for a formula like:

```
S(a) = S(m) * {calculations here}
```

For the system message it isn't that hard I guess, as it only has two parameters that affect the `Sa` (date and importancy level). So it's scoring formula could look like (`I` is numeric importancy level):

```
S(a) = S(m) * I * (1 / (now() - date_posted())
```

Let's assume a notice would have I=10 and announcement has I=20, the scores for a notice posted yesterday and an announcement posted 2 days ago, would be:

```
Notice:       S(a) = 100 * 10 * (1 / 1) = 1000
Announcement: S(a) = 100 * 20 * (1 / 2) = 1000
```

Now for the documents, and I'm really breaking my head on that one...

I've got the following parameters to take into account:

```
V(o) = number of views
V(a) = average number of views
C(o) = total number of comments
C(a) = average number of comments on this type of object
C(u) = number of comments by the user
SH(o) = total number of shares of this object
SH(a) average number of views of this type of object
SH(u) = has the user shared the document (1 = no, 2 = yes)
T = number of enlisted tags
```

I found a simplified example of how Facebook calculates 'virality' [here](http://blog.pageyourself.com/how-virality-works-on-facebook/). They use the following formula:

```
Rank = Affinity * Weight * Decay
```

And if I translate that to my use-case, the affinity would be the outcome of a calculation on the parameters listed above, the weight would be the score-max altered a bit based on the total number of views and shared divided by the average number of views and shares, and the decay would be a complex calculation based on the correlation of the events fired and the date the object was created.

I'm giving it a try:

```
Affinity = C(u) * SH(u) * T * SH(u)
Weight   = S(m) * (V(o) / V(a)) * (SH(o) / SH(a)) * (C(o) / C(a))
Decay    = (1 / (now() - date_created())) * (1 / (now() - date-of-last-comment())
```

This will get me some kind of ranking, but it lacks a few things:

- it has no relation whatsoever with the ranking of a system message, and thus sorting would be meaningless
- the frequency of new comments isn't taken into account

So now I'm stuck...

To get to the point, my questions are:

- Is this a good approach, or should I try something totally different?
- If so, what direction should I go to?